# Adding/Importing a ready coded (AboutUs) page into Joomla

Tags: php, html, joomla, import, ftp

I am busy converting a HTML website into a Joomla temaplate, I got some help doing the home page (index.php), but now the menu items are not linking anywhere. I have a ready coded AboutUs.php page, which I want to important into Joomla and link to the 'About Us' menu item.

Can this be done in the similar way as it is done with the index.php file? Can I maybe upload the file via FTP and link it somehow in Joomla?

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is probably better asked over on http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Neil will do that too

Answer (score 0):

No it's not how joomla works.

You have to create the second menu item, link it with your content and add the extra modules that your "about us" page have.

If you don't want to do it like that you could create a new template and link each menu to different template but it's not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to migrate a site and use a tool like joomla i strongly suggest using it the way it was designed to be used. Otherwise theres no point.

When creating from scratch or migrating a site to joomla i would suggest firstly creating (or modifying) one or more templates to get the layout of you site; header, footer, logo, background, modules (eg. menu, login, etc) and component to load and so on.

You will have to recreate the menu items using the menu manager and apply your css to the menu module(you can download free menu modules or use the default one or develop one).

When creating a menu item you can select the template to be used and also what component you want to load (article, sitemap, blog, login, create user, etc...). An article is used to store html content which can be edited through the content manager although there are simple ways to add scripts to your articles.

If you want to add php to your content you have 4 choices.

**Template** (used to show content which appears on every page; this is where the html starts and ends and where the component and modules' positions are defined),

**Component** (this is loaded from the template depending on what menu item is selected),

**Module** (a very simple and easy way to add custom php and html code, can be loaded from the template or from components like in a joomla article),

**Plugin** (used when wanting to run scripts which dont have any visual content)

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested about the html part of the php site,
you can just create an article and paste html code in it (do not forget to set the editor in text mode).
If you have css, you may add it int the template's css file.

Otherwise, if you need php functionality, you need to create a joomla component.